# \sffamily does not show Greek characters

Tags: xetex, greek, sans-serif

I have been trying to generate a timetable for my weekly schedule via a GNU SF template that I've found. As I'm Greek, I wanted the text in the schedule to be in Greek.

The template I use is [Pascal Gwosdek's](http://www.planetk.de/index.php/Personen) timetable.sty package, which generates a nice looking weekly timetable, like so:

[image]

**The problem begins** when I attempt to change the days into the Greek equivalents, in the `timetables.sty` package, like so:

```
\newcommand{\greekdays}[1]
{
    % Arguments: <number of start day>
    % Macro for the greek week days
    % added by dsfounis

    \setcounter{@day}{#1}

    \@ttforloop{@column}{1}{\value{@column} < \value{@colcount}}
    {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}1}{\daymark{Δευτέρα}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}2}{\daymark{Τρίτη}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}3}{\daymark{Τετάρτη}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}4}{\daymark{Πέμπτη}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}5}{\daymark{Friday}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}6}{\daymark{Saturday}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}7}{\daymark{Sunday}}{}

        \stepcounter{@day}
        \ifthenelse{\value{@day} > 7}{\addtocounter{@day}{-7}}{}
    }
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

I've identified the lines that set the font for most elements of the timetable to be these ones:

```
% SansSerif font
\newcommand{\timetablefont}{\sffamily}
\newcommand{\@ttfont}{\timetablefont\selectfont}
```

**Is there any way to properly show Greek characters in \sffamily?** I thought Computer Modern Sans Serif included Greek symbols.

I could also change the font to Ubuntu basic, which is suitable for the timetable and looks good, but I do not know how to do this through the above 2 lines.

---

**Minimal working example (Default template apart from the /greekdays command rewrite)**

**`.tex`:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

% Definitions
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[height=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{timetable}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\printheading{Stundenplan 6. Semester}
% Define the layout of your time tables
\setslotsize{3.8cm}{0.3cm}
\setslotcount {5} {36}
\settextframe{0.8mm}
\setbottomstyle{\tiny}
\setbottomspace{1pt}
\setprinttimestamps{2}
\setframetype[t]{1}
\seteventcornerradius{0pt}
\definecolor{ttframecol2}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
% Define event types
\defineevent{corelecture}{0.0} {0.28}{1.0} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{seminar} {1.0} {0.4} {0.2} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{langcourse} {1.0} {0.4} {0.2} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{tutorial} {0.6} {0.8} {1.0} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{work} {0.21}{0.5} {0.16}{1.0}{1.0}{1.0}

% Start the time table
\begin{timetable}
\hours{9}{15}{0}
\greekdays{1} %MARKER
\event 1 {1415} {1600} {Data Networks Lecture} {Druschel} {E1{\tiny3} 002} {corelecture}
\event 1 {1615} {1800} {Tutorial SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny3} SR014} {work}
\event 2 {0915} {1100} {Embedded Systems Lecture} {Finkbeiner} {E1{\tiny3} 003} {corelecture}
\event 2 {1115} {1300} {Differential Equations in IPCV Lecture} {Weickert} {E1{\tiny3} 001} {corelecture}
\event 2 {1415} {1600} {Office Hour SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny1} HaDePra} {work}
\event 3 {1415} {1600} {Data Networks Lecture} {Druschel} {E1{\tiny3} 002} {corelecture}
\event 3 {1615} {1800} {Numerical Algorithms in Image Analysis} {Bruhn, Weickert} {E1{\tiny1} 3.06} {seminar}
\event 4 {0915} {1100} {Embedded Systems Lecture} {Finkbeiner} {E1{\tiny3} 003} {corelecture}
\event 4 {1115} {1300} {Tutorial SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny3} SR014} {work}
\event 5 {1000} {1100} {Bremser Meeting} {SysArch United} {E1{\tiny3}} {work}
\event 5 {1115} {1300} {Differential Equations in IPCV Lecture} {Weickert} {E1{\tiny3} 001} {corelecture}
\end{timetable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**`timetable.sty`**

```
%    timetable.sty - The LaTeX timetable stylesheet V1.4
%    http://www.planetk.de/index.php?title=Stundenplan
%
%    Copyright (C) 2007-2009 Pascal Gwosdek
%    Modifications (C) 2008 Daniel Bader
%
%    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
%    under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
%    Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or (at your
%    option) any later version.
%
%    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
%    WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
%    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
%    Public License for more details.
%
%    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
%    with this program; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{timetable}
\RequirePackage{ifthen, calc, color}

% Preset the colors
\definecolor{ttframecol1}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{ttframecol2}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{ttfontcolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{ttlinecol1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{ttlinecol2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}

% Simple for loop construct as proposed by N. Setzer
\newcommand{\@ttforloop}[5][1]
{
  \setcounter{#2}{#3}
  \ifthenelse{#4}
  {
    #5
    \addtocounter{#2}{#1}
    \@ttforloop[#1]{#2}{\value{#2}}{#4}{#5}
  }
  {}
 }

% SansSerif font
\newcommand{\timetablefont}{\sffamily}
\newcommand{\@ttfont}{\timetablefont\selectfont}

% Dimensions
\newlength{\@rowheight}
\newlength{\@colwidth}
\newcounter{@rowcount}
\newcounter{@colcount}
\newlength{\@textframe}
\newlength{\@bottomspace}
\newlength{\@totalheight}
\newlength{\@totalwidth}
\newlength{\@toprowheight}

% Arbitrary stuff
\newcounter{@timemarks}
\newcounter{@daymarks}
\newcounter{@topheight}
\newcounter{@printtimestamps}
\newlength{\@cornerradius}
\newcounter{@frametype}
\newcounter{@framevalign}

% Predefines
\setlength{\@cornerradius}{3pt}
\setcounter{@frametype}2
\setcounter{@framevalign}2
\setlength{\@rowheight}{1.2cm}
\setlength{\@colwidth}{2.8cm}
\setlength{\@textframe}{0.8mm}
\setlength{\@bottomspace}{8pt}
\setcounter{@rowcount}9
\setcounter{@colcount}5
\setcounter{@topheight}{2}
\setcounter{@printtimestamps}{0}
\newcommand{\@bottomstyle}{\scriptsize}
\newcommand{\@timestyle}{\tiny}

% Event declarations
\newlength{\@startposx}
\newlength{\@startposy}
\newlength{\@eventheight}
\newlength{\@newcolwidth}
\newlength{\@newrowheight}
\newlength{\@newcolleft}
\newlength{\@newrowtop}

% Helpers
\newcounter{@hourslot}
\newcounter{@durationslots}
\newcounter{@minutesperslot}
\newcounter{@timetablehelp}

\newcounter{@day}
\newcounter{@column}
\newcounter{@row}
\newcounter{@hour}
\newcounter{@minute}
\newcounter{@minuteStep}
\newcounter{@startHour}
\newcounter{@startMinute}
\newcounter{@endHour}
\newcounter{@endMinute}
\newcounter{@hoursset}
\setcounter{@hoursset}{0}
\newcounter{@hourzero}

\newcommand{\seteventcornerradius}[1]
{
  \setlength{\@cornerradius}{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\strip@pt\@cornerradius > 7}
  {
    \setlength{\@cornerradius}{7pt}
  }
  {
    \ifthenelse{\strip@pt\@cornerradius < 0}
    {
      \setlength{\@cornerradius}{0pt}
    }
    {}
  }
}

\newcommand{\settopheight}[1]
{
    \addtocounter{@rowcount}{#1-\value{@topheight}}
    \setcounter{@topheight}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\setframetype}[2][c]
{
  % Set frame type
  \ifthenelse{#2 < 1}
  {
    % Lines
    \setcounter{@frametype}{1}
  }
  {
    \ifthenelse{#2 > 2}
    {
      % Checkerboard
      \setcounter{@frametype}{2}
    }
    {
      \setcounter{@frametype}{#2}
    }
  }

  % Caption vertical alignment
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}
  {\setcounter{@framevalign}{1}}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}
    {\setcounter{@framevalign}{0}}
    {\setcounter{@framevalign}{2}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\setprinttimestamps}[1]
{
    \setcounter{@printtimestamps}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\setbottomstyle}[1]
{
    \renewcommand{\@bottomstyle}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\settimestyle}[1]
{
    \renewcommand{\@timestyle}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\setbottomspace}[1]
{
    \setlength{\@bottomspace}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\@fmtTime}[2]
{
    % Arguments: {hour}{minute}
    \ifthenelse{\value{#1} < 10}{0}{}\arabic{#1}:\ifthenelse{\value{#2} < 10}{0}{}\arabic{#2}
}

\newcommand{\slotevent}[7]
  {
    % Arguments: {x}{y}{duration}{title}{lecturer}{place}{type}{textcolor}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.75}\normalsize

    \setlength{\@startposx}{#1\@colwidth+0.5pt}
    \setlength{\@startposy}{-#2\@rowheight-1.5pt}
    \setlength{\@eventheight}{#3\@rowheight-1pt}
    \addtolength{\@startposy}{-\@eventheight}

    \addtolength{\@startposx}{\@cornerradius}
    \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@colwidth-1pt-2\@cornerradius}{\@eventheight}}}
    \addtolength{\@startposx}{-\@cornerradius}
    \addtolength{\@startposy}{\@cornerradius}
    \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@colwidth-1pt}{\@eventheight-2\@cornerradius}}}
    \addtolength{\@startposy}{-\@cornerradius}

    \setlength{\@cornerradius}{2\@cornerradius}

    \ifthenelse{\strip@pt\@cornerradius > 0}
    {
      % Left rounded corners
      \addtolength{\@startposx}{.5\@cornerradius}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{.5\@cornerradius-\dp\strutbox}
      \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\circle*{\strip@pt\@cornerradius}}}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{-.5\@cornerradius+\dp\strutbox}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{-.5\@cornerradius-\dp\strutbox+\@eventheight}
      \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\circle*{\strip@pt\@cornerradius}}}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{.5\@cornerradius+\dp\strutbox-\@eventheight}
      \addtolength{\@startposx}{-.5\@cornerradius}

      % Right rounded corners
      \addtolength{\@startposx}{-.5\@cornerradius+\@colwidth-1pt}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{.5\@cornerradius-\dp\strutbox}
      \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\circle*{\strip@pt\@cornerradius}}}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{-.5\@cornerradius+\dp\strutbox}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{-.5\@cornerradius-\dp\strutbox+\@eventheight}
      \put(\strip@pt\@startposx,\strip@pt\@startposy){\textcolor{@timetable#7block}{\circle*{\strip@pt\@cornerradius}}}
      \addtolength{\@startposy}{.5\@cornerradius+\dp\strutbox-\@eventheight}
      \addtolength{\@startposx}{.5\@cornerradius-\@colwidth-1pt}
    }{}

    \setlength{\@cornerradius}{0.5\@cornerradius}

    \setlength{\@newrowheight}{\@rowheight}
    \addtolength{\@newrowheight}{-2\@textframe-1pt}
    \setlength{\@newcolwidth}{\@colwidth}
    \addtolength{\@newcolwidth}{-2\@textframe-1pt}

    \setlength{\@newrowtop}{-#2\@rowheight}
    \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-2\@textframe}
    \setlength{\@newcolleft}{#1\@colwidth+.5pt}
    \addtolength{\@newcolleft}{\@textframe}

    \ifthenelse{\value{@hoursset} = 0}{\setcounter{@printtimestamps}{0}}{}

    % Title
    \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-1pt}
    \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop)
        {\begin{minipage}[t]{\@newcolwidth}%
          \@ttfont\raggedright\color{@timetable#7text}%
            \ifthenelse{\value{@printtimestamps} > 0}%
              {{\@timestyle \@fmtTime{@startHour}{@startMinute}}%
                \ifthenelse{\value{@printtimestamps} = 2}%
                  {{\@timestyle -- \@fmtTime{@endHour}{@endMinute}}}%
                  {}%
              \\}%
              {}%
            {#4}%
         \end{minipage}}
    \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{1pt}

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}\normalsize
    \setlength{\@newrowtop}{-#2\@rowheight-#3\@rowheight}
    \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{2\@textframe + \@bottomspace}

    % Lecturer
    \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop)
        {\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\@newcolwidth}%
      \@ttfont\raggedright\color{@timetable#7text}{\@bottomstyle #5%
            \vphantom{A}}
            \ifthenelse{\value{@printtimestamps} = 1}%
              {{\@timestyle \@fmtTime{@endHour}{@endMinute}}}%
              {}%
          \end{minipage}}

    \setlength{\@newcolleft}{#1\@colwidth + \@colwidth}
    \addtolength{\@newcolleft}{-\@textframe-0.4\@newcolwidth}

    % Location
    \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop)
      {\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\@newcolwidth}%
        \@ttfont\raggedleft\color{@timetable#7text}{\@bottomstyle #6%
          \vphantom{A}}%
      \end{minipage}}

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize
  }

\newcommand{\event}[7]
  {
    % Arguments: {@day}{@start}{@end}{title}{lecturer}{place}{type}

    % Use the time format, if hours are defined, and a slot number otherwise:
    \ifthenelse{\value{@hoursset} > 0}
    {
      \setcounter{@startHour}{#2 / 100}
      \setcounter{@startMinute}{#2 - #2 / 100 * 100}

      \setcounter{@endHour}{#3 / 100}
      \setcounter{@endMinute}{#3 - #3 / 100 * 100}

      \setcounter{@hourslot}{((#2 - \value{@hourzero}) / 100 * (60 / \value{@minutesperslot})) + 2 + ((#2 - #2 / 100 * 100) / \value{@minutesperslot})}
      \setcounter{@durationslots}{((#3 - \value{@hourzero}) / 100 * (60 / \value{@minutesperslot})) + 2 + ((#3 - #3 / 100 * 100) / \value{@minutesperslot}) - \value{@hourslot}}

      % Compensate for 24h wrap
      \ifthenelse{\value{@hourslot} < 0}{\addtocounter{@hourslot}{(24 * (60 / \value{@minutesperslot}))}}{}

      \addtocounter{@hourslot}{\value{@topheight}-2}
    }
    {
      \setcounter{@hourslot}{#2}
      \setcounter{@durationslots}{#3-#2}
    }

    \slotevent{#1}{\value{@hourslot}}{\value{@durationslots}}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}
  }

\newcommand{\legend}[3]
  {
    % Arguments: <horizontal> <vertical> <text>
    % Lets you manually set slot contents (use this really rarely and
    % SEE: \daymark, \timemark )

    \setlength{\@newrowtop}{\@rowheight*(-#2+1)-\dp\strutbox}
    \setlength{\@newcolleft}{#1\@colwidth-\@colwidth}

    \ifthenelse{\value{@hoursset} = 0}
      {\setcounter{@minutesperslot}{60}}
      {}

    % Select frame type
    \ifthenelse{\value{@frametype} = 1}
    { % Lines
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1}{\put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop){\textcolor{ttframecol2}{\rule{\@colwidth}{1pt}}}}{}
      \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}
      \addtolength{\@newcolleft}{-1pt}
      \ifthenelse{#2 = 1}{\put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop){\textcolor{ttframecol2}{\rule{1pt}{\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}}}}{}
      \addtolength{\@newcolleft}{1pt}
      \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}
    }
    { % Checkerboard
      % Horizontal stripe
      \ifthenelse{#2 = 1}
        {\setcounter{@timetablehelp}{#1 * \real{0.5} * \real{2.0}}
          \ifthenelse{\value{@timetablehelp} = #1}
            {\addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}
             \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop)
               {\textcolor{ttframecol2}{\rule{\@colwidth}{\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}}}
             \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}
            }
            {}
        }
        {}
      % Vertical stripe
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1}
        {\setcounter{@timetablehelp}{(((#2-\value{@topheight}-1) * \value{@minutesperslot} / 120) * 2) - ((#2-\value{@topheight}-1) * \value{@minutesperslot} / 60)}
          \ifthenelse{\value{@timetablehelp} = 0}
            {\setcounter{@timetablehelp}{60 / \value{@minutesperslot}}
             \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-\value{@timetablehelp}\@rowheight}
             \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop)
               {\textcolor{ttframecol2}{\rule{\@colwidth}{\value{@timetablehelp}\@rowheight}}}
             \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{\value{@timetablehelp}\@rowheight}
            }
            {}
        }
        {}
    }

    % Print text
    \addtolength{\@newcolleft}{\@textframe}
    \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{-\@textframe-\heightof{\large #3}}

    % Optionally move caption to middle or bottom
    \ifthenelse{\value{@framevalign} > 0}
    {
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1}
      {
        \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{(- \@rowheight * (60 / \value{@minutesperslot}) + 2\@textframe + \heightof{\Large #3})/\value{@framevalign}}
      }
      {
        \ifthenelse{#2 = 1}
        {
          \addtolength{\@newrowtop}{(- \value{@topheight}\@rowheight + 2\@textframe + \heightof{\Large #3})/\value{@framevalign}}
        }{}
      }
    }{}

    \put(\strip@pt\@newcolleft,\strip@pt\@newrowtop){\makebox{\textcolor{ttfontcolor}{\@ttfont\large #3}}}
  }

\newcommand{\timemark}[1]
  {
    \stepcounter{@timemarks}
    \legend 1 {\value{@timemarks}} {#1}
  }

\newcommand{\daymark}[1]
  {
    \stepcounter{@daymarks}
    \legend {\value{@daymarks}} 1 {#1}
  }

\newcommand{\defineevent}[7]
  {
    \definecolor{@timetable#1block}{rgb}{#2, #3, #4}
    \definecolor{@timetable#1text} {rgb}{#5, #6, #7}
  }

\newcommand{\printheading}[1]
  {
    {\@ttfont\LARGE #1}\par\vspace{5mm}\par
  }

\newcommand{\setslotsize}[2]
  {
    % Arguments: <width> <height>
    % Defines the slot size

    \setlength{\@rowheight}{#2}
    \setlength{\@colwidth}{#1}
  }

\newcommand{\setslotcount}[2]
  {
    % Arguments: <days> <hours per day>
    % Defines the number of slots in both dimensions

    \setcounter{@colcount}{#1}
    \setcounter{@rowcount}{#2+\value{@topheight}}

    \stepcounter{@colcount}
  }

\newcommand{\settextframe}[1]
  {
    % Arguments: <width>
    % Defines the width of the border of each entry (i.e. the
    % distance between outer border and text)

    \setlength{\@textframe}{#1}
  }

\newcommand{\hours}[3]
  {
    % Arguments: <start hour> <minute stepping> <print end time?>
    % Automatically sets the time slots to full hours, beginning with <start hour>

    \setcounter{@hoursset}{1}
    \setcounter{@hourzero}{(#1 * 100)}

    \setcounter{@hour}{#1}
    \setcounter{@minute}{0}
    \setcounter{@minuteStep}{#2}
    \setcounter{@minutesperslot}{\value{@minuteStep}}

    \@ttforloop{@row}{\value{@topheight}}{\value{@row} < \value{@rowcount}}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\value{@minute} = 0}{
        \timemark{\@fmtTime{@hour}{@minute}\ifthenelse{#3 > 0}{-\setcounter{@hour}{\value{@hour}+1}\@fmtTime{@hour}{@minute}\setcounter{@hour}{\value{@hour}-1}}{}}
      }{\stepcounter{@timemarks}}
      \addtocounter{@minute}{#2}
      \ifthenelse{\value{@minute} = 60}{\stepcounter{@hour}\setcounter{@minute}{0}}{}   
      \ifthenelse{\value{@hour} > 23}{\addtocounter{@hour}{-24}}{}
    }
  }

\newcommand{\englishdays}[1]
  {
    % Arguments: <number of start day>
    % Macro for the english week days

    \setcounter{@day}{#1}

    \@ttforloop{@column}{1}{\value{@column} < \value{@colcount}}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}1}{\daymark{Monday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}2}{\daymark{Tuesday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}3}{\daymark{Wednesday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}4}{\daymark{Thursday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}5}{\daymark{Friday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}6}{\daymark{Saturday}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}7}{\daymark{Sunday}}{}

      \stepcounter{@day}
      \ifthenelse{\value{@day} > 7}{\addtocounter{@day}{-7}}{}
    }
  }

\newcommand{\germandays}[1]
  {
    % Arguments: <number of start day>
    % Macro for the english week days

    \setcounter{@day}{#1}

    \@ttforloop{@column}{1}{\value{@column} < \value{@colcount}}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}1}{\daymark{Montag}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}2}{\daymark{Dienstag}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}3}{\daymark{Mittwoch}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}4}{\daymark{Donnerstag}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}5}{\daymark{Freitag}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}6}{\daymark{Samstag}}{}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}7}{\daymark{Sonntag}}{}

      \stepcounter{@day}
      \ifthenelse{\value{@day} > 7}{\addtocounter{@day}{-7}}{}
    }
  }

\newcommand{\greekdays}[1]
{
  % Arguments: <number of start day>
  % Macro for the greek week days
  % added by dsfounis

  \setcounter{@day}{#1}

  \@ttforloop{@column}{1}{\value{@column} < \value{@colcount}}
  {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}1}{\daymark{Δευτέρα}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}2}{\daymark{Τρίτη}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}3}{\daymark{Τετάρτη}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}4}{\daymark{Πέμπτη}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}5}{\daymark{Friday}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}6}{\daymark{Saturday}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}7}{\daymark{Sunday}}{}

    \stepcounter{@day}
    \ifthenelse{\value{@day} > 7}{\addtocounter{@day}{-7}}{}
  }
}

\newenvironment{timetable}%
  {\noindent%
    % Arguments: None
    % Starts a new timetable
    %
    % Set the new layout setting
    \setlength{\@totalheight}{-\value{@rowcount}\@rowheight}%
    \setlength{\@totalwidth}{\value{@colcount}\@colwidth}%
    %
    % Reset the counters
    \setcounter{@timemarks}{\value{@topheight}}%
    \setcounter{@daymarks}{1}%
    %
    % Minipage to correct bounding box
    \begin{minipage}[t][-\@totalheight]{\@totalwidth}
    %
    % Begin. Note the offset hack of the picture, this is to make it consistent to the old pstricks package. 
    \begin{picture}(\strip@pt\@totalwidth,\strip@pt\@totalheight)(0,-\strip@pt\baselineskip)
      % Draw the grey frame
      \put(0,\strip@pt\@totalheight){\textcolor{ttframecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@colwidth}{-\@totalheight}}}
      \setlength{\@toprowheight}{\value{@topheight}\@rowheight}
      \put(0,-\strip@pt\@toprowheight){\textcolor{ttframecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@totalwidth}{\@toprowheight}}}
  }
  {
      % Draw the contours
      % Inner
      \addtolength{\@colwidth}{-1pt}
      \put(\strip@pt\@colwidth,-\strip@pt\@toprowheight){\textcolor{ttlinecol2}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@totalwidth-\@colwidth+1pt}{1pt}}}
      \put(\strip@pt\@colwidth,\strip@pt\@totalheight){\textcolor{ttlinecol2}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{-\@totalheight-\@toprowheight}}}
      \addtolength{\@colwidth}{1pt}

      % Outer
      \put(0,0){\textcolor{ttlinecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@totalwidth}{1pt}}}
      \put(0,\strip@pt\@totalheight){\textcolor{ttlinecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{-\@totalheight}}}
      \put(\strip@pt\@totalwidth,\strip@pt\@totalheight){\textcolor{ttlinecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{-\@totalheight+1pt}}}
      \addtolength{\@totalheight}{-0.5pt}
      \put(0,\strip@pt\@totalheight){\textcolor{ttlinecol1}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\@totalwidth}{1pt}}}
      \addtolength{\@totalheight}{0.5pt}
    \end{picture}

    \end{minipage}
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg It's kind of irrelevant, since all the work in the `.tex` file is done by using commands in the `.sty` package. I have no problem with compiling, I just want to get the font to work with greek letters in these two lines in the package.

Since I'm a beginner though, a minimal working example could reveal a problem that I'm missing. Adding it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add support for Greek to begin with. The simplest way is to use `babel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

% Definitions
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[height=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{timetable}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\printheading{Stundenplan 6. Semester}
% Define the layout of your time tables
\setslotsize{3.8cm}{0.3cm}
\setslotcount {5} {36}
\settextframe{0.8mm}
\setbottomstyle{\tiny}
\setbottomspace{1pt}
\setprinttimestamps{2}
\setframetype[t]{1}
\seteventcornerradius{0pt}
\definecolor{ttframecol2}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
% Define event types
\defineevent{corelecture}{0.0} {0.28}{1.0} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{seminar} {1.0} {0.4} {0.2} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{langcourse} {1.0} {0.4} {0.2} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{tutorial} {0.6} {0.8} {1.0} {1.0}{1.0}{1.0}
\defineevent{work} {0.21}{0.5} {0.16}{1.0}{1.0}{1.0}

% Start the time table
\begin{timetable}
\hours{9}{15}{0}
\greekdays{1} %MARKER
\event 1 {1415} {1600} {Data Networks Lecture} {Druschel} {E1{\tiny3} 002} {corelecture}
\event 1 {1615} {1800} {Tutorial SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny3} SR014} {work}
\event 2 {0915} {1100} {Embedded Systems Lecture} {Finkbeiner} {E1{\tiny3} 003} {corelecture}
\event 2 {1115} {1300} {Differential Equations in IPCV Lecture} {Weickert} {E1{\tiny3} 001} {corelecture}
\event 2 {1415} {1600} {Office Hour SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny1} HaDePra} {work}
\event 3 {1415} {1600} {Data Networks Lecture} {Druschel} {E1{\tiny3} 002} {corelecture}
\event 3 {1615} {1800} {Numerical Algorithms in Image Analysis} {Bruhn, Weickert} {E1{\tiny1} 3.06} {seminar}
\event 4 {0915} {1100} {Embedded Systems Lecture} {Finkbeiner} {E1{\tiny3} 003} {corelecture}
\event 4 {1115} {1300} {Tutorial SysArch} {Gwosdek} {E1{\tiny3} SR014} {work}
\event 5 {1000} {1100} {Bremser Meeting} {SysArch United} {E1{\tiny3}} {work}
\event 5 {1115} {1300} {Differential Equations in IPCV Lecture} {Weickert} {E1{\tiny3} 001} {corelecture}
\end{timetable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\greekdays` should be

```
\newcommand{\greekdays}[1]
{%
  % Arguments: <number of start day>
  % Macro for the greek week days
  % added by dsfounis
  %
  \setcounter{@day}{#1}%
  %
  \@ttforloop{@column}{1}{\value{@column} < \value{@colcount}}
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}1}{\daymark{\textgreek{Δευτέρα}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}2}{\daymark{\textgreek{Τρίτη}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}3}{\daymark{\textgreek{Τετάρτη}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}4}{\daymark{\textgreek{Πέμπτη}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}5}{\daymark{Friday}}{}% %%%%FIX HERE!
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}6}{\daymark{Saturday}}{}% %%%%FIX HERE!
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{@day}}7}{\daymark{Sunday}}{}% %%%%FIX HERE!
    %
    \stepcounter{@day}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{@day} > 7}{\addtocounter{@day}{-7}}{}%
  }%
}
```

I believe it should be in the document preamble, rather than a change in the `timetable.sty` file. Precede the code by `\makeatletter` and follow it by `\makeatother`, in this case. Why? Because if the package author changes it, you'll lose your change.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply and suggestions :3
Unfortunately, I get the same result when I compile your code. Plus, a compiler warning. http://i.imgur.com/sg3mDI9.png

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis First of all, fully update your MiKTeX.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis egreg's code is for pdftex, but your image shows an error from xetex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updating MiKTeX and recompiling with pdftex now.

Comment: @egreg Finally updated by MiKTeX and compiled with pdftex. Your code works as I wanted. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @egreg  a related question is posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269326/sample-file-of-gwosdek-timetable-with-mwf-times-on-left-and-tr-on-the-right). How we create a time axis on left for certin days of the week and another time axis on right for the remaining days?